# NSIS Password Registry Encryption

Tags: encryption, nsis

Right now im storing passwords in plain text in the registry, i'd prefer not to use plugins, but does NSIS have any built in methods to actually encrypting plain text into the registry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most string things can be done with the basic building-blocks; `StrCpy`, `StrCmp` and`StrLen`. For encryption/decryption you might need [Asc](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Asc) and `IntFmt $foo "%c" $bar` as well.

You probably have to code the implementation yourself by inventing a new algorithm (Never invent crypto unless you know what you are doing) or using some existing scheme ported to NSIS. To me this seems like too much work just to avoid using a plugin.

A much better option IMHO would be to call the [protected storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) with the system plugin...